# MVC TimeSpan Value Not Returning To Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I attempt to post my data back to the database, the time values are not in the model.  They display just fine when retrieving data though.

Here is the Model:

```
public class Schedule
{
    [DisplayName("Build Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan Build_Time { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Start Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan Call_Start_Time { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("End Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan Call_End_Time { get; set; }
```

Post Controller:

```
    // POST: RecurringTemplate/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RecurringTemplate recurringTemplate)
    {
        try
        {
            _repo.AddRecurringTemplate(recurringTemplate);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View Objects:  (The model is a viewmodel the Schedule class is in)

```
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Schedule.Build_Time)
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Schedule.Build_Time, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}}) 

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Schedule.Call_Start_Time)

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Schedule.Call_Start_Time, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Schedule.Call_Start_Time, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Schedule.Call_End_Time)
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Schedule.Call_End_Time, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
```

All of the other controls I have for the view are posting back with no problem, I just can't get the time to return.  I just shows {00:00:00} for the times in the debugger.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the view model the Schedule class is in:

```
    public class RecurringTemplate
{
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public List<Filters> Filters { get; set; }
    public List<BuildDays> BuildDays { get; set; }
    public List<Offsets> Offsets { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduleTypes> ScheduleTypes { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select BuildDays")]
    public List<byte> SelectedBuildDays { get; set; } 
    public byte SelectedScheduleType { get; set; }
    public decimal FilterId { get; set; }
}
```

*EDIT*
I have found the issue, and I apologize I didn't realize I left this part out initially.  I have a custom UI for time picking [DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)... And if I remove this javascript the values are returning to the controller:

```
    @* Time Picker *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Schedule_Build_Time").datetimepicker({
            format: "LT"
         });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas or experience with this?

Comment: Show us the code of your `EditorFor` template.

Comment: is your controller expecting a Schedule class?

Comment: @ MelanciaUK I added the view model.  The controller expects the RecurringTemplate